# Skipping filename while calculating hash in Java

Tags: java, hash

Is there a way to skip filenames while calculating the hash of a file in Java? I'm currently using the MD5 hashing routine provided by Java.

This is the method I'm using:

```
public static String MD5(File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));

    int theByte = 0;
    while ((theByte = in.read()) != -1) {
      md.update((byte) theByte);
    }
    in.close();

    byte[] theDigest = md.digest();

    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(theDigest));
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(theDigest);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Show us your code sir. We are no wizards that could judge code that we can't look at.

Comment: do you want to create hashes only with the content of a file?

Comment: What have you tried, think, research? The simpler would be to simply rename the file just to create the MD5...

Comment: I could simply rename the file, but that would require me to change the existing code quite a lot, and keep track of where the files are being saved, to avoid naming clashes. I was wondering if there was a method to only calculate hash of the contents of the file itself.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'skipping'. The filename isn't affecting the result of your method when creating hash. Only the content of the file is involved in hash creation.

Comment: as @exoddus says, you iterate over the content of the file, and "skipping the name of the file". In other words, you are not already including file name into your hash.

Comment: Thanks exoddus, Muatik, for clearing up the issue about the filename. It turned out that it was a problem with the contents of the file, not the filename.